# Spark: How do I pass a PartialFunction to a DStream?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-collections, spark-streaming

I'm trying to pass a partial function to the union of all the RDDs captured in a DStream batch over a sliding window. Lets say I construct a window operation over 10 seconds on a stream discretized into 1 second batches:

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(new SparkConf(), Seconds(1))
val stream = ssc.socketStream(...)
val window = stream.window(Seconds(10))
```

My `window` will have K many RDDs. I want to use `collect(f: PartialFunction[T, U])` on the union of all K of these RDDs. I could call the union operator `++` using `foreachRDD`, but I want to return an `RDD` not a `Unit` and avoid side effects.

What I'm looking for is a reducer like

```
def reduce(f: (RDD[T], RDD[T]) ⇒ RDD[T]): RDD[T]
```

on a `DStream` that I can use like so:

```
window.reduce(_ ++ _).transform(_.collect(myPartialFunc))
```

But this is not available in the Spark Streaming API.

Does anyone have any good ideas for combining RDDs captured in a stream into a single RDD so I can pass in a partial function? Or for implementing my own RDD reducer? Perhaps this feature is coming in a subsequent Spark release?

Comment: The compute function will allow you to get an RDD over a time period.

Comment: @Anant Where does the period begin and end? The DStream method `compute` only accepts a `validTime` parameter. Is this the start or end of my window? Also, how will I deal with having to repeatedly call `compute` on the same interval as my batches? I'm looking for something less stateful.

Comment: @nmurthy You cannot do `collect` on a DStream. Could you further explain what you're trying to do? There's probably another way.

Comment: @maasg Correct, I'm trying to call `collect` on the union of all the RDDs captured in one DSteram interval. There are two steps to what I'm trying to do: (1) reduce all the RDDs in one DStream interval with the `++` operator into a single RDD, and then (2) call`collect` on my _reduced_ RDD using a DStream transform.

Comment: And what would you do with the result of the `collect` afterwards? `collect` is not much more than combining `filter` and `map` that are available on the `DStream` API - not sure why it's required to union the RDDs, though.

Comment: @maasg I could use a _filter-map_ operation on a DStream, but I want to use a partial function. Currently, partial functions can only be passed into RDDs using `collect` which is not available on DStreams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial functions are not directly supported by a DStream operation, but it's not difficult to achieve the same functionality.

For example, let's take a trivial partial function that takes a String an produces an Int of the String if it's a number:

```
val pf:PartialFunction[String,Int] = {case x if (Try(x.toInt).isSuccess) => x.toInt}
```

And we have a dstream of Strings:

```
val stringDStream:DStream[String] = ??? // use your stream source here
```

Then we can then apply the partial function to the DStream like this:

```
val intDStream = stringDStream.filter(x => pf.isDefinedAt(x)).map(pf)
```